Isolated worker function apps can't find queues with custom storage connections
I have an isolated worker function in .net 8 that i want to use appsettings.json for all the configuration (NOT Environment Variables).  Why? Because we use appsettings.json in the other three projects in this solution and we want this managed in the same way, we need to deploy to 100+ function apps and i do not want to script environment variable changes in that way.  I want to use the appsettings.json file in a similar configuration to how we've always used it with regular .net 6 apps.
This function for example
  public async Task ProcessPasswordResets([QueueTrigger("password-resets", Connection = "ConnectionStrings:PrimaryFileStorage")] ResetPasswordMessage message, FunctionContext fc)

....
Will never fire even though there is a queue with the name "password-resets" at the storage account using connection string "PrimaryFileStorage" in a node called "ConnectionStrings" in the appsettings.json.
having a "flat" local.settings.json file with similar setup works fine.
Adding storage services or other connections in Program.cs using something like _config["ConnectionStrings:PrimaryFileStorage"] works fine as well.  It seems the only place it can't navigate away from "AzureWebJobsStorage" (default connection string) is the declaration of the QueueTrigger in the function call method itself.
This is a windows Azure Function app that is relying on timer and queue triggers mostly.  When i use Env Variables everything works, but i REALLY do not want to, finding it hard to understand why the isolated-worker functions seem to have such issues and wondering if it's a bug?
I've tried everything, flattening the appsettings.json file, trying every conceivable configuration in Program.cs.  I am at the point where i think i should just revert this back to .net 6 and roll the dice they will figure it out in a year.


having a "flat" local.settings.json file with similar setup works fine.

In Function Apps, One should store connection string in local.settings.json and not in app settings.
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "rithcon": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwikbd86;AccountKey=XM6FQ2u/fI+bxpnpW5sk+AStWMDXrg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}


If you get connection string from appsettings.json then you have to use _config["rithcon"] in program.cs.
If you deployed to azure:
If you want to use appsettings.json one way is
public void Run([QueueTrigger("rithq", Connection = "%rithcon%")] QueueMessage message)

appsettings.json:
{
  "rithcon": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwikbd86;AccountKey=XM6FQ2u/tSuffix=core.windows.net"
}

Then in csproj add:
  <None Update="appsettings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
      <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>

So when deployed the value of rithcon i stored in Environment Variables section and then function app takes it from there:


Spirit of my question is that i do not want to use Env Variables ya? i have 100+ apps 100+ function apps, i don't want to adjust every deployment script i have to move from appsettings.json to environment variables or this completely ridic Azure App Config service which is just a glorified wrapper for a Key Vault connection riddled with latency issues.

Also
public void Run([QueueTrigger("rithq", Connection = "%rithcon%")] QueueMessage message)
that don't work on Azure, yes works fine locally.  put it on an app service, none of the binding triggers work with any setup in appsettings.json, no queue triggers, no timer triggers.  These MUST be in Env variables to use a separate connection, or need to use AzureWebJobsStorage connection as that is what it looks at by default.
